# @Html.DropDownListFor not posting back to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using `@Html.DropDownListFor` for the first time. Code is below.

**Model:**

```
class Student
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Roll Number")]
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ClassId")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

}

class Class
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ClassId")]
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ClassName")]
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Student student = new BusinessEntities.Student();
    List<Class> classes = GetAllClasses();
    ViewBag.ClassId = new SelectList(classes, "ClassId", "ClassName");
    return View(student);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BusinessEntities.Student student)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Integer has 0 by default. But in our case if it contains 0, 
      //means no class selected by user
      if(student.ClassId==0)
      {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ClassId", "Select Class to Enroll in");
        return View(student);
      }
    }
}
```

**Student Create View:**

```
<form  method="post">
    Select Class : 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model=>Model.ClassId,ViewBag.ClassId as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "ClassId","ClassName")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.ClassId)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Error Message:**

> The ViewData item that has the key 'ClassId' is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[BusinessEntities.Class, BusinessEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

I want `ClassId` of `Student` be binded and populated automatically when posted back to Controller. Please help me to get rid of it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `SelectList` a different name that the property your binding to (say)

```
ViewBag.ClassList = new SelectList(classes, "ClassId", "ClassName");`
```

and then

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClassId, ViewBag.ClassList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

and then ensure if you return the view (for example if `ModelState` is invalid), that you repopulate the `SelectList` (as you have done in the GET method). Currently when you return the view, it is `null` resulting in an error, because if the second parameter is `null` the fallback is that the helper expects the first parameter to be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (but its not - its typeof `int`)

Side notes: Do not use `Model => Model.XXX` (capital M) and your current use of `DropDownistFor()` as 2 parameters which make no sense. `"ClassId"` will add a label option `<option value="">ClassId</option>` and the last one `,"ClassName"` will not do anything.

**Edit**

In addition, your

```
if(student.ClassId==0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("ClassId", "Select Class to Enroll in");
    return View(student);
}
```

is a bit pointless. `student.ClassId` will never be `0` unless one of the items in your `GetAllClasses()` has `ClassId = 0`. You should be using

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Class to Enroll in")] // add error message here
public int ClassId { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClassId, ViewBag.ClassList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--please select--")
```

which will create the first option with a value of `null`. If this option were selected, then the `DefaultModelBinder` will attempt to set the value of `ClassId = null` which fails (because typeof `int` cannot be `null`) and a `ModelState` error is added and `ModelState` becomes invalid.

The in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BusinessEntities.Student student)
{
  if (!ModelSTate.IsValid)
  {
    ViewBag.ClassList = // repopulate select list
    return View(student);
  }
  // Save and redirect
}
```

Comment: See also update regarding the code in your POST method